# Magento blocks doubling

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento blocks doubling after migration from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.2

```
<reference name="right">
            <block type="core/template" name="adsone" template="callouts/right_col.phtml">
                <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/advertise-section/adsone.png</src></action>
                <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Advertisement</alt></action>
            </block></reference>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to show this banner only once. Now in the right position this ads block showing two times

Comment: And what is holding you back to post that in your question?